# in Java, intersection of two sets using the add and contains methods, with iterators

Tags: java, iterator, set, addition, intersection

How can you compute the intersection of two sets using the add and contains methods, along with iterators?

I have the code:

```
private static void intersection(Set<Comparable> setOne, Set<Comparable> setTwo){
    Iterator<Comparable> iter = setOne.iterator();
    Iterator<Comparable> iterator = setTwo.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()){
        if (!setTwo.contains(iter.next())){
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        if (!setOne.contains(iterator.next())){
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
    setOne.addAll(setTwo);
    System.out.println(setOne.toString());
}
```

However, it always returns an empty set, meaning it removes the elements from the sets despite the case in the if statement.

Comment: Start with a new empty set, then iterate through `setOne` and add elements that also exist in `setTwo`. Change your function to return the new set, instead of mutating the existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

How did you run this code? It works perfectly. Are you sure that you are launching the correct main method? Do you see empty brackets [] or what's your result? Are you using the correct data? How do you fill the sets? It should be something like, [1, 2] and [2, 3] and then it will print out [2].

Answer (score 0):

An easy way, assuming that, doing it as suggested is not required is as follows:

```
      Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<>(Set.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
      Set<Integer> b = new HashSet<>(Set.of(3, 4, 5, 6, 7));
      List<Integer> saveA = new ArrayList<>(a);

      a.removeAll(b);
      saveA.removeAll(a);

      System.out.println(saveA);
```

If you must use iterators, you could do it like this.

```java
      Iterator<Integer> iterA = a.iterator();
      Iterator<Integer> iterB = b.iterator();

      Set<Integer> inter = new HashSet<>();
      while (iterA.hasNext()) {
         int r = iterA.next();
         if (b.contains(r)) {
            inter.add(r);
         }
      }
      while (iterB.hasNext()) {
         int r = iterB.next();
         if (a.contains(r)) {
            inter.add(r);
         }
      }

      System.out.println(inter);
```